# Модуль 'skimage.data' не имеет атрибута 'imread'

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn

Установил scikit-images, импортировал skimage в код. Ошибок с самой функцией `skimage` нет, но в строках:

```
for f in file_names:
    images.append(skimage.data.imread(f))
    labels.append(int(d))
```

При запуске кода выдает ошибку:

> AttributeError: module 'skimage.data' has no attribute 'imread'

С чем может быть связано и как можно решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по [документации](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread) надо делать так:

```
from skimage.io import imread

images.append(imread(f))
# ----------> ^^^^^^^^^
```

PS скорее всего разработчики перенесли функцию `imread` в submodule `io` в более новых версиях.

Comment: @mIbI А что говорит `print(skimage.__version__)`? В Google Colab версия `0.16.2`, она не ругается.

Comment: @CrazyElf Проблема уже была решена, но всё же , версия 0.18.2

Comment: @mIbI То есть ваш комментарий про ошибку `AttributeError: module 'skimage' has no attribute 'io' ` уже не актуален? Если да, то удалите его. А то непонятно - вроде проблема и решена, а вроде вы пишете, что ошибка.

Comment: Удалил, извините, что ввёл в заблуждение.